# Binding Redirect for PresentationFramework?

Tags: .net, .net-assembly

In Windows 11 22H2 and version 4.8.9093.0 of PresentationFramework.dll Microsoft kindly introducted a NullReferenceException within the CloseToolTip method.

Extract from Event Viewer:

> Exception Info: System.NullReferenceException at System.Windows.Controls.PopupControlService.CloseToolTip(System.Windows.Controls.ToolTip)

This has caused some random crashes in my application. Note the issue only exists on machines running the latest Windows 11.

Now to resolve this issue I can replace the broken version of the DLL in `C:\Windows\Microsoft.NET\assembly\GAC_MSIL\PresentationFramework\v4.0_4.0.0.0__31bf3856ad364e35` with a working version. In this case 4.8.4536.0 and it works like a charm!

This is not really something I can just do on a client machine though, so I was going to add a binding redirect with a copy of the DLL in the installation folder, but this does not appear to be working as I still see the crash and using dnSpy I can see it loading the broken DLL from the GAC.

Here is the setup of my redirect. I have also tried adding `publicKeyToken="31bf3856ad364e35"` but this causes the application to not launch at all.

```
<dependentAssembly>
    <assemblyIdentity name="PresentationFramework" culture="neutral" />
    <bindingRedirect oldVersion="0.0.0.0-4.8.9093.0" newVersion="4.8.4536.0" />
    <codeBase version="4.8.4536.0" href="PresentationFramework.dll" />
 </dependentAssembly>
```

Any ideas of how I can overcome this?

EDIT:

I found this

> If the assembly was referenced with a public key (which it will be if
> you compiled against the GAC assembly) then the loader uses the GAC to
> load it.  If it can't find it in the GAC then it uses probing of the
> local directory to find the assembly.

So I think I will need to create a new build of my application with PresentationFramework referenced from a different location, as there appears to be no way to force the runtime to use a local version of a DLL over one in the GAC. Very annoying.

Comment: bindingRedirect can't solve this, it redirects the [AssemblyVersion] and its the same (4.0.0.0).  If you want a workaround then you'll need to do it the stackoverflow-way: post repro code.

Answer (score 1):

After many hours spent searching, I finally found a solution. It appears this was related to some new ToolTip changes, for WCAG 2.1 accessibility or something. I don't really understand it to be honest.

I added this line to my app.config and it works as expected.

```
<runtime>
    <AppContextSwitchOverrides value="Switch.System.Windows.Controls.ToolTip.OptOutOfWCAG21ToolTipBehavior=true"/>
</runtime>
```